# Get value of a property in another object tree inside braces

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Here is what i have (simplified of course):

```
my.property = 15
...
page {
    page.someproperty < my.property
}
```

There are two conditions:

- I can not rename `my.property`
- I have to reference it **inside** the braces of `page`

Though my example is not working (verification appreciated), I guess everybody gets the point.

This is a *very simple* setup and I can not get why *nobody* in this whole internet ever had that issue.

Well... I guess I'm missing the question mark here.. so here is the actual question: Can anybody give me a working example that meets the above two conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my.property` is not a valid property. First of all you must prefix a property with either `lib` or `temp`. The first one is a "Library" object and will be cached while the second one is a "Temporary" object and will be deleted after runtime.

Besides that, your example doesn't include any TypoScript objects. So even if it works, it won't output anything.

So this should work:

```
lib.myproperty = TEXT
lib.myproperty.value = Hello world!

page = PAGE
page {
  # PAGE is a COA so we need a numerical index
  10 < lib.myproperty
}
```

Output in browser:

```
Hello world!
```

Comment: The `lib`-/`temp`-thing is a very good point, I didn't know it. About that there are no objects; It was simply a matter of simplicity. Of course my actual code has TS objects. But indeed you are right, my example is bad. Summarized: Thanks :)